# How to count how many times every year shows up in my dataset in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

wondering if anyone can help me.

I have a dataset with the column "created_at" which has rows like this

```
data = pd.read_csv("dataset.csv")
col = data["created_at"]
print(col.head())
print(col.tail())

0    2014-06-01 21:03:16
1    2014-06-01 09:06:48
2    2014-06-01 00:31:52
3    2014-06-04 10:04:47
4    2014-06-04 10:05:40
Name: created_at, dtype: object
380064    2019-05-31 23:49:39
380065    2019-05-31 23:52:34
380066    2019-05-31 23:27:28
380067    2019-05-31 14:01:31
380068    2019-05-31 12:30:33
Name: created_at, dtype: object
```

I'm trying to count how many times each year appears so how many times does the year 2014 appear and 2015 and so on.

I've tried counters and for loops but I just can't seem to get it to work. If anyone can help, would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First convert your column into `datetime` type because I see that it is in `object` type:

```
data['created_at'] = pd.to_datetime(data['created_at'])
```

Now extract the `year` part using `dt`:

```
data['year'] = data['created_at'].dt.year
```

Finally, do the count using `value_counts`:

```
data.year.value_counts()
```

Sample Output:

```
data.year.value_counts()
Out[142]: 
2014    3
2015    2
Name: year, dtype: int64
```